# How to get the same vals in a more flatten data-structure in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

So I have this data structure :

```
(def params
  {:site1
    {:index-element
       {:date  "2012-10-10"
        :title "Hello"}
     :subpage-element
        {:time     "9:00"
         :location "Toronto"}}
   :site2 …})
```

I want to change it to a more flatten data structure

```
(def new-params  
  {1
    {:name     :site1
     :date     ["2012-10-10" :index-element]
     :title    ["Hello"      :index-element] 
     :time     ["9:00"       :subpage-element]
     :location ["Toronto"    :subpage-element]}
   2 …})
```

To get the results I wanted I do :

```
(mapv #(-> params % :index-element vals)
      (keys params))
```

How would I get same result with new-params?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's three ways:

```
;;; 1.
(reduce-kv (fn [res siteno m]
             (->> (vals m)
                  (filter #(and (vector? %)
                                (identical? :index-element (peek %))))
                  (map first)
                  (conj res)))
           []
           new-params)

;;; 2.
(->> new-params
     (vals)
     (map vals)
     (map (partial filter #(and (vector? %)
                                (identical? :index-element (peek %)))))
     (mapv (partial map first)))

;;; 3. (better than 2., but only for Clojure >= 1.5)
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(->> new-params
     (vals)
     (r/map vals)
     (r/map (partial filter #(and (vector? %)
                                  (identical? :index-element (peek %)))))
     (r/map (partial map first))
     (into []))
```

Switch to `mapv` (in the anonymous function in 1., in the last `partial` in 2. & 3.) to get a vector of vectors instead of a vector of lazy seqs (and thereby make construction of the inner collections non-lazy -- this may well make sense).

The original data structure is actually more suited to this kind of access; there's no avoiding the linear searches with the flatter maps. This might be a performance problem, depending on access patterns and the actual data.

Comment: Great post, thanks! I am actually surprised that it is this complicated. I guess you're right, even though flatten maps tend to be cleaner, in that case, it makes it more complicated to get back the vals associated with :index-element.

Answer (score 3):

One option would to be use `for` (which, in IMHO makes it more readable):

```
(->> (for [[i site] new-params]
       (for [ [s-k s-v] site
              :when (not= s-k :name)
              :let [[k [v v-k]] [s-k s-v]]
              :when (= v-k :index-element)]
         v))
     (into []))
```